# radmenuitem click event" not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

In My Application ( which uses Asp.net and language:C#) horizontal multiple column "radmenuitem click event" not working after publishing and the this Application and it is working flawlessly on local host

Anyone Please Help me.

Comment: Code sample or more discription would help coz We don't know what is "radmenuitem click event"!

Comment: At first, please have a look [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if you problem is the same as mine was, but for me in my Xaml I was using `MouseLeftButtonDown`  for triggering my events and it was not working.  After doing some searching and reading I found that I was supposed to be using the `Click` keyword instead.
So 
my Xaml now looks like this:

```
   <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Import" Click="XML_LeftButtonDownImport"/>
```

and the c# behind:

```
  private void XML_LeftButtonDownImport(object sender, RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
  // Do your operations here, in my case it was an open file dialog.
}
```

Make sure that you use `RadRoutedEventArgs` instead of just `RoutedEventArgs` or `System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs` as the latter two will result in errors.

Hope this was helpful.